# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.getActiveTab().barColor)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native and I am unable to resolve below issue.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   this.getActiveTab().barColor)

The above error occurs in below component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import home from "../../../assets/home.png";
import form from "../../../assets/home.png";
import contact from "../../../assets/home.png";
import BottomNavigation, {
  FullTab, Tab
} from 'react-native-material-bottom-navigation';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
export default class BottomView extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeTab: 0 };
  }

  handleTabChange = (newTabIndex, oldTabIndex) => {
        this.setState({ activeTab: newTabIndex });
        if (newTabIndex === oldTabIndex) {
          null;
        }
        if (this.state.activeTab === 0) {
        } else if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
        } else {
        }
    }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>   
                <BottomNavigation
                    activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
                    labelColor="#5c007a"
                    rippleColor="white"
                    style={{
                      height: 56,
                      elevation: 8,
                      position: 'absolute',
                      left: 0,
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 0
                    }}
                    onTabChange={this.handleTabChange}
                >
                    <Tab 
                      barBackgroundColor="#fff"
                      label="Home"
                      icon={<Icon size={24} color="#5c007a" name="home" />}
                    />
                    <Tab 
                      barBackgroundColor="#fff"
                      label="Categories"
                      icon={<Icon size={24} color="#5c007a" name="list" />}
                    />
                    <Tab
                      barBackgroundColor="#fff"
                      label="Profile"
                      icon={<Icon size={24} color="#5c007a" name="person" />}
                    />
                </BottomNavigation>
            </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation for react-native-material-bottom-navigation; it seems quite different than how you're using. The tabs object are in an array and then passed to bottom navigation. https://timomeh.gitbook.io/material-bottom-navigation/usage#rendering-a-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two potential problems are..

1) It looks like you're trying to import a Tab component from 'react-native-material-bottom-navigation', but from what their API docs are showing, it looks like the components this package provides are:

- Badge
- BottomNavigation
- FullTab
- IconTab
- ShiftingTab

https://github.com/timomeh/react-native-material-bottom-navigation/tree/master/docs/api

I'd suggest looking deeper into their docs on how to use the components they provide.

2) You're importing Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'.

I went to that part of their docs, and the way you're implementing does not match the way they're suggesting you do it. To resolve that specific problem, swap out all occurrences of `Icon` with `MaterialIcons`

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/MaterialIcons.js

Comment: I'm going to try and replicate your error on my end in the meantime, but I'm confident that I've at least got you in the right direction if those proposed solutions don't work.